# How to query an XML Column within a mySQL Database correct?

Tags: mysql, xml, mysql-5.7

I have a mySQL Column, called Data, which field type = LongBlob.
In there, I have an XML Document for every supplier.
The saved XML Document looks like this:

```
<BarcodeList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Clientgroups>
    <clientgroup clientgroupID="0" />
  </Clientgroups>
  <Articles>
    <Article articleID="HS1" articleName="Air HG">
      <Configuration>
        <Feature selectedValue="846566843718" templateID="UpcCode" />
        <Feature selectedValue="14.2" templateID="Diameter" />
        <Feature selectedValue="8.6" templateID="RadiusBasecurve" />
      </Configuration>
    </Article>
   </Articles>
</BarcodeList>
```

Of course, in my real world data, there are a lot of articles within this XML File.
Now, I get the input of: "846566843718" and need the Diameter, RadisuBaseCurve and articleID back.
How can I achieve this?

My mySQL Server Version: 5.7
I tried some SQL code, but this runs more than 1 Minute and without any result.

```
SELECT * FROM xmldata s WHERE EXTRACTVALUE(s.Data, "//Feature[@selectedValue='846566843718']");
```

And:

```
SELECT * FROM xmldata s WHERE EXTRACTVALUE(s.Data, "/BarcodeList/Articles/Article/Configuration/Feature/selectedValue='846566843718']");
```

Comment: How many rows has the table and how big is the XML document in each row?

Comment: Hey
The rows in the table are not so many - About 10
But the rows in the XML Document are about 530000 lines -> Means about 100000 Articles

Comment: That sounds like something you should consider for extracting into a separate table with a foreign key to your suppliers table and a proper index. Querying this kind of volume of data in its current form will never be efficient.